# Where does xmlHttp.responseText get the text from?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use xmlHttp.responseText to get a list of options (i.e. Blahblah), etc.

However, when I try to generate a list of them with PHP, and use XMLHttp.responseText, it seems to pull the whole page.

How do I make sure to only get a specific string from a page, and can it be used to get tags, as well? (I specifically want the tags)

This is the page that the XMLHttp is making a call to:

```
<?php
include "mysql_config.php";
$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect to the database, please contact administrator');
}
mysql_select_db($db);
while ($cultrow = mysql_fetch_array($rescult)) {
        ECHO '<option name="culture[]" value="'. stripslashes($cultrow['cult_id']) .'">'. stripslashes($cultrow['cult_desc']) .'</option>';
    }
    ?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If I understand your question you need to create the separate php-script which will generate AJAX response (not a whoole html-page).

Comment: `responseText` will contain the data returned by the server. So you get whatever your PHP script returns.

Comment: How would I do this? Currently my PHP response is this (posted above)

Comment: So `repsonseText` will be a string consisting of `<option>` tags... what do you want now?

Comment: That's what I want, but that isn't what seems to be coming over.

Comment: Well... we don't know what you get. Make sure you call the right URL. Also, if you are using a framework, it might add further data to the response.

Comment: My console.log even seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot. I was using innerHTML as a function.

Comment: Delete your question, since it will probably not be useful to future visitors.